# Wordpress 3,5 and Jquery version

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I updated my WordPress installation to latest version (3.5)when i am looking at source code of my site, i saw following lines

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/myblog/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
```

It seems like WordPress is only loading un-minifed version of Jquery, Is there any way i can configure it to load minified version in production?

I am unable to find any minified version under `/wp-includes/js/jquery`

Comment: Load that link in a browser. Is it minified? It is when I look at it on my site.

Comment: @s_ha_dum it seems like that , but the size of same version from Google CDN is way less that what is being loaded by Wordpress

Comment: Does Google's CDN version use compression?

Comment: Firebug's "Net" tab lists Google's jQuery 1.8.3 as 32.7k and WordPress' Core jQuery 1.8.3 as 32.7k.

Comment: @s_ha_dum: http://tools.pingdom.com shows wordpress version as `91.8 kB` while google CDN version of `33.1 kB`, which created confusion to me, may be google using some sort of compression

Comment: I just checked Pingdom and got 33k for both but my server does compress output.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3269314/1094518), Google does indeed compress its jQuery (or it did, three years ago).

Answer (score 1):

WordPress includes the minified version of jQuery as `jquery.js` rather than using `jquery.min.js`. I don't see any uncompressed version of it anywhere in the latest release of 3.5 (I'm looking at 3.5.3 right now).

They've made some other changes to how development and production assets are loaded. There are now several files that are `*.dev.js` and `*.dev.css` for use in development. These are the "regular" versions of those files, and the ones without `.dev.` are the production/minified versions. An example of how this is used is at http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug.

If you look through the `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` folders, you'll see the previous method of providing the uncompressed file used in development along with the minified one for production use.